# How to export DataGridView as PDF using iText7, (Note: Not Using iTextSharp) in C#?

Tags: .net, pdf, datagridview, datatable, itext7

I found lots of examples of how to export DataGridView and DataTable to PDF using iText Sharp, which is an older version of iText7, but I would like to how we can do it using iText7 including Headers,
Thanks in advance

Comment: There appears to be a fairly robust tutorial on the iText7 website… [iText 7: Jump-Start Tutorial for .NET](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net) … Are you stuck at some point that the tutorial is missing? Your question is to broad and without more details and specifics will likely be closed. I recommend a visit to the [SO Help Center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,
Hi :),
you can use for & foreach and getting the data from selected DGV to the table...
Please, see the code below:

```
        private Table PDFTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv, float [] cloumnwidth)
    {
        // Getting Rows & Columns Counts
        int dgvrowcount = dgv.Rows.Count;
        int dgvcolumncount = dgv.Columns.Count;

        // Set The Table like new float [] {15f, 15f, 15f, 15f, 15f }
        Table table = new Table(cloumnwidth);
        table.SetWidth(iText.Layout.Properties.UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

        // Print The DGV Header To Table Header
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvcolumncount; i++)
        {
            Cell headerCells = new Cell()
                          .SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)
                          .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
            //headerCells.SetNextRenderer(new RoundedCornersCellRenderer(headerCells));
            var gteCell = headerCells.Add(new Paragraph(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText));
            table.AddHeaderCell(gteCell);
        }

        // Print The DGV Cells To Table Cells
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvrowcount; i++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < dgvcolumncount; c++)
            {
                Cell cells = new Cell()
                          .SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.WHITE)
                          .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
                          
                var gteCell = cells.Add(new Paragraph(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[dgv.Columns[c].HeaderText].Value.ToString()));
                table.AddCell(gteCell);
            }
        }

        return table;
    }
```